# Rails template tags documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where can I find the documentation for Rails template/layout tags?  I'd like to find a complete list of the tags I can use.

Bonus points if the documentation is available for 2.3.X

Comment: You mean the helper_method like form_for etc?

Comment: e.g. `<% if`, `<% else`, etc.

Comment: That's just ruby. Any valid ruby can go inside <% %> or <%= %> - there's no specific if tag, else tag etc

Comment: Ah.  Post as an answer and I'll accept.  The moar you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<% if, <% else and so on aren't tags that rails defines.

Instead erb allows you to use <% and <%= to embed arbitrary ruby code into the templates

Comment: Thanks.  Coming from Django this was new to me